# I would like to record single frame with an external trigger, exposure starting accuracy not relevant

Tags: camera, pi-5

I am recording droplets with a synchronized LED, and I would like to trigger my raspberry pi hq camera externally. It says in the manual that recording a single frame is not possible, but all I need is the exposure to be open for 0.001 sec around the 1 microsecond flash duration. The manual says I need a professional camera for that, for example a basler dart. But it looks like a raspi camera with global shutter should also do the job. Any advice?

Comment: please ask a specific, answerable question... `Any advice?` is too broad, and is in reality a yes/no question

Comment: is it possible to send an external trigger to the raspberry pi HQ camera, so that i can record a single frame (synchronized with the stroboscopic flash)